# Why are additional items not being added to my dictionary in Robot Framework?

Tags: python, selenium, dictionary, robotframework

I'm creating a dictionary in Robot Framework, which uses Python language. The dictionary has keys which are variables containing YES or NO values.

```
${MONDAY}        YES
${TUESDAY}       YES
${WEDNESDAY}     NO
${THURSDAY}      NO
```

The dictionary has values which are also variables but contain locators.

```
Days_Monday = "css = input[id^= 'entity.applicableDays.en-GB.0.']"
Days_Tuesday = "css = input[id^= 'entity.applicableDays.en-GB.1.']"
Days_Wednesday = "css = input[id^= 'entity.applicableDays.en-GB.2.']"
Days_Thursday = "css = input[id^= 'entity.applicableDays.en-GB.3.']"
```

I was then going to iterate over the dictionary as there are corresponding checkboxes correlating to the locators which should be selected depending on whether a value is YES or NO. The code for the iteration works (which I have omitted from my query) but I'm having issues with the dictionary itself. I added a `log to console` in order to see what was happening

```
Select Days
    [Arguments]     ${MONDAY}        ${TUESDAY}       ${WEDNESDAY}     ${THURSDAY}
    &{dict} =   Create Dictionary    ${MONDAY}=${Days_Monday}    ${TUESDAY}=${Days_Tuesday}     ${WEDNESDAY}=${Days_Wednesday}    ${THURSDAY}=${Days_Thursday}
    log to console      ${dict}
```

When I call `Select Days`, the console displays `{'YES': "css = input[id^= 'entity.applicableDays.en-GB.1.']", 'YES': "css = input[id^= 'entity.applicableDays.en-GB.2.']"}`

I was expecting to see `{'YES': "css = input[id^= 'entity.applicableDays.en-GB.1.']", 'YES': "css = input[id^= 'entity.applicableDays.en-GB.2.']", 'NO': "css = input[id^= 'entity.applicableDays.en-GB.3.']", 'NO': "css = input[id^= 'entity.applicableDays.en-GB.4.']" }`

I have checked indentations and this doesn't seem to be the case. I also checked to see if dictionaries were restricted to 2 items, which is also not the case. Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Code works as expected: you are creating a dictionary with two keys, "YES" and "NO". So the first "YES" (GB.0) is overwritten with the second "YES" (GB.1). Same for "NO" key. A workaround might be a list inside a key.

Comment: @Pekka Thanks for this information. It had completely slipped my mind that dictionary keys need to be unique and understandably the values were overwritten in the process of me creating the dictionary, due to it being a mutable datatype. I will try using the locators as keys instead, with the (YES/NO) as values but I will also take your suggestion on board if this fails. Appreciate it!